# Regex to match only with minimum number of characters in the whole match

Tags: regex

I have this regex **pattern**

```
(\d?[a-z]*\d+[a-z]*-?\d*[a-z]*\d*)
```

and e.g. this **subject**

new balance mrl420 grey - is een strakke lichtgewicht sneaker van New Balance voor heren. De MRL420 serie van New...

So this matches mrl420

But what I want is that it will only return a match when the whole match is 7 characters or more, so in this case it should not match but in this case:

new balance mrl420grey - is een strakke lichtgewicht sneaker van New Balance voor heren. De MRL420 serie van New...

is should give a match.

I've tried e.g.

```
(\d?[a-z]*\d+[a-z]*-?\d*[a-z]*\d*){7,} or (\d?[a-z]*\d+[a-z]*-?\d*[a-z]*\d*).{6,}
```

but this does not provide the right answer. It seems that then the 7 characters limitation only applies to the last element, in this case the number of digits?

So how do I get the result I want? So to sum it up:

first test the regex pattern match 
if it matches at all check whether it has 7 characters or more.

Of course this could be done in two separate steps, but can it be done with one expression as well?

Comment: Try [`\b(?=[a-z\d-]{7})\d?[a-z]*\d+[a-z]*-?\d*[a-z]*\d*`](https://regex101.com/r/7SNFiU/1)

Comment: Olaf, does it work as intended? The starting pattern can be also written as `\b(?=\S{7})`, but I am just not sure you want to start matching the substrings after a word boundary. Please confirm.

Comment: Is there a pattern to a minimum-size match? Could you give us some examples? What you need is a minimum number of each part (digit, letter, etc.)

Comment: @ Whothehellisthat Does not matter, i.e. the pattern works fine but has in this case to be limited to return only when 7 characters or more.

Comment: @ Wiktor: yes this seems to work! So you use a look ahead in this case. Didn't think of that!

But what do you mean by "I am just not sure you want to start matching the substrings after a word boundary"?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  It looks like you've cracked this question.  Please reply to Olaf and/or post an answer to be accepted.

Comment: @mickmackusa: Thank you. Olaf, when providing feedback, please do not add space between `@` and username

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: good point, rookie here...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: done and thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
\b(?=[a-z\d-]{7})\d?[a-z]*\d+[a-z]*-?\d*[a-z]*\d*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7SNFiU/1)

**Details**:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?=[a-z\d-]{7})` - immediately after the word boundary position, there must be 7 chars: letters, digits or `-` (`i` case insensitive modifier can be used to match both upper- and lower-case letters)
- `\d?` - 1 or 0 digits
- `[a-z]*` - 0+ letters
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `[a-z]*` - zero or more letters
- `-?` - an optional hyphen
- `\d*` - 0+ digits
- `[a-z]*` - 0+ letters
- `\d*` - 0+  digits.